# Run a script every time a new shell is spawned

Tags: bash

I need to make it so that every time /bin/bash is executed, a script /tmp/some/thing is executed within the shell that is spawned. Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your script call in .bashrc file. So in .bashrc, call your script like:

```
. ${MY_SCRIPT_PATH}/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to do this for /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash?
What I actually need is a script that will be running at all times under all users and will automatically start if a new shell is spawned.

Comment: if you have .profile, then you could run the script from there.

Comment: Still not running for /bin/sh

Comment: You wrote "_every time /bin/bash is executed_". The only tag that you've used is [bash], why don't you accept an answer and ask another question?

Comment: You asked about Bash, and this solves it for Bash. If you have a different question now, (mark this as accepted and) post it as a new, separate question. (But no, there is no similar, simple solution for `/bin/sh`. The `.profile` is only run for login shells.)